# Java 8 stream returns list from element

Tags: java, java-8

There is a simply:

```
public class Task{
   private String name;
   private List<Task> subtasks;
}
```

and a list of `Task` objects. How is it possible to get list of every `Task` as `subtask` by using `stream()`.
I tried this one:

```
List<Task> subtasks = myTask.stream().map(x -> x.getSubtasks()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but it returns `List<List<Task>>`. What is the best way to join array from `map()` to existing result?

Comment: Can subtasks have subtasks?

Comment: Use `flatMap(x -> x.getSubtasks().stream())` instead of your `map()`

Comment: @Holger good point, missed that it's using `Task` inside `Task`. If the rabbit hole doesn't go deeper, that duplicate should do.

Comment: @Kayaman: I added another one for the recursive case…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    List<Task> subtasks = myTask.stream()
            .flatMap(x -> x.getSubtasks().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```